# Resize font according to monitor resolution

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and am having difficulty adjusting the font size. When the display resolution changes, the text exceeds the div limit. I would like, rather than going beyond the limit of the div, that the text would change the resolution according to the rest of the layout.

Screenshot

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="sec" id="se">

    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <img class="img" src="img/i.jpg">
    <div class="secleft">
        <div class="txt">
        <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT..</p>
        <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT..</p>
        <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT..</p>
        <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT..</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="secright">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sec{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009fb2;
    top: 75%;   
}
.title{
    position: absolute;
    height: 15%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
    top: 5%;
    left: 30%;
}
.img{

    position: relative;
    width: 16%;
    left: 42%;
    top: 28%;   
}

.secleft{
    position: absolute;
    height: 57%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #006672;
    top: 28%; 
    left: 7%;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.txt{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what CSS Media Queries are for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

You can use `@media (max-width: 750px) {css here..}`

What this does is it applies different CSS depending on the width of the screen. So you can apply a different font-size inside this block, this will then only be used when the screen is less than 750 pixels wide. Note 750 is just an example and can be set to whatever you like.

Example:

```
body {
    font-size: 3em;
    }

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    body {
    font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use pixels for font-sizing. Use em's or rem's instead.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The unit `em` is relative to it's parent. Define several breakpoints using media queries and change the font-size of the parent, and it's children will scale down relative to their parent.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/jpa1fab8/

As you can see the font-size changes relative to their container. 
*Drag the divider in the JSFiddle to make the container smaller*

So: define your `font-size` as `em` and use `@media` to change `font-size` based on certain `breakpoints`. These are the breakpoints Bootstrap CSS uses: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/

Answer (score -3):

set the font size with following css:

```
font-size: 1vw;
```

Comment: You should use em's or rem's for font-sizing instead, and change it's size with media queries